# Can't dynamically add Web User Controls

Tags: asp.net

I understand the page lifecycle and how I need to add the dynamic controls on `page_init` if I want to take advantage of viewstate. And I already have read a lot of topics regarding the issue but it was not very useful.

I have to work with the solution where I have a set of user controls, that inherit one interface and then I add/delete them dynamically to a literal control. I can't load them at once in a `page_init` because later I have to delete/add them based on user actions. These controls contains a button, and its post back event handler is fired only when I generate this user control at `page_init` or `page_load` methods.

So I have to somehow reinitialise/restart lifecycle of the page after needed processing in some `Button_Click`, (where I update the controls list) events handlers. That is not possible, as I have found. Redirecting to the same page is not a solution, because in the case I will lost my whole viewstate.

So I am stuck, could you please help me with the solution?

Comment: Are you talking about custom server controls or web user controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you could benefit from creating a [CompositeControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol.aspx).

I recently answered a similar question based on dynamically creating textboxes in which I provided a fairly detailed example.

See: [Dynamically add a new text box on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676182/dynamically-add-a-new-text-box-on-button-click/7677202#7677202)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean that I should create one composite control that will be static on a page and which will dynamically populate my web user controls? So it will be like an advanced repeater or a literal in my case?  Or can I dinamically work with set of composite controls as I wanted to do with user controls?

Comment: Add your CompositeControl (statically) to the page, which will act as a container for all your dynamic controls, which you can generate as required by using the CreateChildControls method.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you need to instantiate the dynamic controls to retrieve their view state, but you're relying on the view state to determine how to instantiate the dynamic controls.

You could utilize the ASP.NET [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)? Use the Session State to store the information from which you generate the dynamic controls.

When you handle the button click event, destroy and recreate all of the controls, and then store all the information you need to recreate them again in the Session State.

The next time the page instantiates, the `page_init` function can check if there's any pertinent info in the Session State, and use this to recreate the controls.

Comment: Actually I utilize Session State and store a list of classes that I use for generation of user controls. But when the user clicks "close" button in one of these user controls, I update the session state in appropriate event handler after page_init, so I steel see the removed user control until next page post back