# Webforms : Simplest way to allow a user to add/remove textboxes?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate, user-controls

I don't want to use a gridview because the rest of the form isn't.

I simply need to be able to create a control to dynamically add/remove textboxes and get the value back either as a list of objects or a comma separated string.. It's proving to be much more difficult than it should.

I tried using Jquery + a regular asp.net textbox, but that only works nicely when they're starting from scratch--prepopulating the DOM with their information becomes a pain.

Is there something painfully simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you could benefit from creating a CompositeControl.

I recently answered a similar question based on dynamically creating textboxes in which I provided a fairly detailed example.

See: [Dynamically add a new text box on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676182/dynamically-add-a-new-text-box-on-button-click/7677202#7677202)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove the input[type=text] elements with jquery, and then use Request.Form in your code behind to get the values by element name.

javascript:

```
var itemCount = 0;
$("#list .add").click(function(){ 
  itemCount++;
  $(this).append("<input type='text' name='item"+itemCount+"'/><button class='remove'>Remove</button>");
});

$("#list .remove").click(function(){ 
  $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

code behind:

```
string value1 = Request.Form["item1"];
string value2 = Request.Form["item2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. The following is made using pure WebForm capabilities. Never do it in the production. It uses **too much viewstate and too much updatepanel**

this is a code behind

```
    public List<String> ValueContainer {
        get {
            return (List<String>)ViewState["ValueContainer"];
        }
        set {
            ViewState["ValueContainer"] = value;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            ValueContainer = new List<string>();
        }
    }
    private void PopulateRepeater() {
        rp1.DataSource = ValueContainer;
        rp1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void lbAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ValueContainer.Add("");
        rp1.DataSource = ValueContainer;
        rp1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void rp1_ItemCommand(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {
        ValueContainer.RemoveAt(e.Item.ItemIndex);
        rp1.DataSource = ValueContainer;
        rp1.DataBind();
    }
```

Here is the markup

```
 <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rp1_ItemCommand" ID="rp1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox" /> <asp:LinkButton Text="Remove" runat="server" ID="lbRemove" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbAdd" onclick="lbAdd_Click" Text="Add" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**This is more lightweight version**

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hfMyField" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function addTextBox() {
        $("#myTextboxesContainer").append($("<input type='text' />").keyup(function () {
            var Data = "";
            $("#myTextboxesContainer input").each(function () {
                Data += $(this).val() + ","; 
            });
            $("#hfMyField").val(Data);
        }));
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<div id="myTextboxesContainer">

</div>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="addTextBox();">Add textbox</a>
```

The idea here is doing all dom manipulations using client script and storing everything in a hidden field. When the data is posted back you can retrive the value of the hidden field in a standard way i.e. `hfMyField.Value`. In this example it is CSV.