# Dynamically created textbox values losses when i click the button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a TextBox dynamically, and i am getting the value of the textbox when i click the button. But the value entered in the dynamic textbox gets empty when i click the button.

Below is my ASPX Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reports.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack = "true">
    <asp:ListItem>Text</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Check</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="GetTextBoxValue" />   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Reports
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox TB = new TextBox();
        TB.ID = "abc";
        form1.Controls.Add(TB);
        Response.Write(Request.Form["abc"]);
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createcontrol();
    }


    protected void createcontrol()
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToLower().Trim() == "text")
        {
            TextBox TB = new TextBox();
            TB.ID = "abc";
            form1.Controls.Add(TB);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it's normal behaviour. When you click button there is a postback and all your controls added dynamically are disapear and create again without value. You can make `Property` which will contain `Dictionary<string,string>` and Key will be ID of created control and Value will be value of it's control. this property have to saved data to `ViewState` or `SessionState` then in method `Update` you should load data to your fresh created control on `Page_Load` event hope this help

Comment: [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676182/dynamically-add-a-new-text-box-on-button-click)

Answer (score 2):

When you use dynamic controls in .NET and want their values to be accessible after postback you need to create them within the Page_Init method of the page. In essence its not working because ViewState has already been set by the time you created the controls. See this guide for detailed info on this topic https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx . To fix the problem elevate your Textbox instantiation code to the Page_Init method and all should be well.