# Composite Control: Not a Known Element

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have found an excellent post (by jdavies) to dynamically add a new text box on button click here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7677202/3620572.

Since this is exactly what I want to do, I have tried this within an asp.net project using c# and it worked fine. I have translated it to vb.net, because I have problems with reading c#.

This is the **control**:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Namespace ASPNetWebApplication.Controls
    Public Class TextBoxCollection
        Inherits CompositeControl
        Private Property TextBoxes() As List(Of String)
            Get
                If ViewState("TextBoxes") Is Nothing Then
                    ViewState("TextBoxes") = New List(Of String)()
                End If

                Return DirectCast(ViewState("TextBoxes"), List(Of String))
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of String))
                ViewState("TextBoxes") = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildControls()
            For Each textBox As String In TextBoxes
                Controls.Add(New TextBox() With { _
                    .ID = textBox _
                })
                Controls.Add(New Literal() With { _
                    .Text = "<br/>" _
                })
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Function GetTextBox(id As String) As TextBox
            Return DirectCast(Controls.Cast(Of Control)().Where(Function(t) (If(t.ID Is Nothing, "", t.ID.ToLower())) = id.ToLower()).SingleOrDefault(), TextBox)
        End Function

        Public Sub AddTextBox(id As String)
            TextBoxes.Add(id)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Markup**:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="ASPNetWebApplication._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="ASPNetWebApplication" Namespace="ASPNetWebApplication.Controls" TagPrefix="ASPNetWebApplication" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ASPNetWebApplication:TextBoxCollection ID="TextBoxCollection1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="AddTextBoxesButton" runat="server" OnClick="AddTextBoxesButton_Click" Text="Add Some Text Boxes" />
    <asp:Button ID="GetTextBoxValuesButton" runat="server" OnClick="GetTextBoxValuesButton_Click" Text="Get TextBox Values" Visible="false" />
    <br />
    <asp:Literal ID="TextBoxEntriesLabel" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

And **codebehind**:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub AddTextBoxesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            TextBoxCollection1.AddTextBox(String.Format("TextBox{0}", i))
        Next
        AddTextBoxesButton.Visible = False
        GetTextBoxValuesButton.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GetTextBoxValuesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        TextBoxEntriesLabel.Text = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            Dim textBoxId As String = String.Format("TextBox{0}", i)
            TextBoxEntriesLabel.Text += String.Format("TextBox: {0}, Value: {1}<br/>", textBoxId, TextBoxCollection1.GetTextBox(textBoxId).Text)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried to do exactly the same to learn, how it works. But in vb.net I have got a warning in default.aspx:

> “Element ‘TextBoxCollection’ is not a known element.”

and an error in default.aspx.designer:

> “Type ‘ASPNetWebApplication.Controls.TextBoxCollection’ is not
>   defined.”

What could be the reason for this errors?

(This is my first question on Stackoverflow and I’m not a good programmer, but I want to learn it. Therefore, please apologize for my unsophisticated question (and my broken English, too). I would really appreciate some tips.)

Comment: I suspect you missed the comment in the post you referred to: "Note: Change Assembly="ASPNetWebApplication" to the name of your assembly."

Comment: @Andrew Morton: Thank you. I named the assembly “ASPNetWebApplication”, just to make everything exactly equal to the example.
Project file: “ASPNetWebApplication.vbproj”
Assembly name: “ASPNetWebApplication”
Root namespace: “ASPNetWebApplication”

Comment: I believe the Namespace statement in VB.NET creates a namespace name that is relative to the project's root namespace.  Try `Namespace Controls` instead of `Namespace ASPNetWebApplication.Controls` and/or examine the generated dll using ILSpy or similar to see what namespace has been generated.

Comment: @Joe: Great! This was all, it works now. Thank you very much! When you create an answer of this, I'll tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `Namespace` statement in VB.NET creates a namespace name that is relative to the project's root namespace. Try Namespace `Controls` instead of Namespace `ASPNetWebApplication.Controls` and/or examine the generated dll using ILSpy or similar to see what namespace has been generated.